# Find if the name is present in three lists of equal size

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I have three lists, each of which has n names. I have to find if there is a name in each of these lists and return it in lexicographical order. The time complexity has to be O(n*log(n)). I've tried the following approach:

1. Sort each of three lists - that's 3n*log(n)
2. Iterate through one list, and compare the name you're currently on to the names in other list, "forgetting" the ones you've already visited.
   On Python it should look something like this:

```py
def find_name(arr1, arr2, arr3):
    arr1.sort()
    arr2.sort()
    arr3.sort()
    idx2 = idx3 = 0
    for name in arr1:
        while idx2 < len(arr2)-1 and name > arr2[idx2]:
            idx2 += 1
        while idx3 < len(arr3)-1 and name > arr3[idx3]:
            idx3 += 1
        if name == arr2[idx2] == arr3[idx3]:
            return name
    return -1
```

And it works on some inputs, but I still think I'm lacking something.

**EDIT:** I've updated my solution. It produces the same result as the Nick's solution, although his is obviously much faster (but my task requires exactly this one).

Comment: Always tag questions with the appropriate language tag(s). That will ensure the maximum number of people see your post.

Comment: Mergesort the lists together then check if any element is repeated three times. That said, your code seems reasonable at first glance, where / how is it failing?

Comment: @tzaman, thanks, that's also a possible solution, of which I also thought, but it requires more memory instead of in-place sorting. I've updated my solution and it works buglessly now.

Comment: @Kenticent If you have a working solution now, you should post it as an answer; after a day you can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use set intersection to find the common names between each of the three lists; this is O(n) for the conversions and the intersection. Then you can take the minimum value of that set, also O(n). For example:

```
def find_name(arr1, arr2, arr3):
    s1 = set(arr1)
    s2 = set(arr2)
    s3 = set(arr3)
    common = s1.intersection(s2, s3)
    return min(common) if len(common) else -1

arr1 = ['bill', 'fred', 'nick', 'jim']
arr2 = ['john', 'nick', 'fred', 'jim']
arr3 = ['jim', 'fred', 'nick', 'joe']

print(find_name(arr1, arr2, arr3))
```

Output:

```
fred
```

If desired, this can be simplified to:

```
def find_name(arr1, arr2, arr3):
    common = set.intersection(set(arr1), set(arr2), set(arr3))
    return min(common) if len(common) else -1
```

or even further to:

```
def find_name(arr1, arr2, arr3):
    return min(set(arr1).intersection(arr2, arr3), default=-1)
```

Thanks to @solid.py and @superbrain for the code enhancements.

Comment: @Kenticent This by far the most efficient solution. If you want to implement your own solution, you could always do that by yourself.